# Laravel: date doesn't work with Model::create()?

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5 and try to put my model to the database like this:

```
Animal::create([
    'name'     => 'Moo',
    'birthday' => '2010-05-05'
]);
```

For some reason, the date is never inserted properly and I'm getting `0000-00-00` instead. I tried with Carbon instance, but it does the same thing.

If I do it this way, it works as expected:

```
$animal = new Animal;
$animal->name = 'Moo';
$animal->birthday = '2010-05-05';
$animal->save();
```

Is it Laravel's bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `birthday` attribute is not fillable. So just add it to the `$fillable` property of the model.